# How to pass information across web pages of a web site

Tags: php, session

I have this website, where I frequently find myself trying to pass information from one web page to the next, what is the best way?  Are sessions pretty much the best option, because what if i need to pass a lot of information? then what?

Comment: Im not sure why having alot of information would make using the session a less desirable approach... if anything it makes it more desirable...

Comment: no need to be a rude about...

Comment: @user719321: I wasnt being rude.. i was jsut saying that i would think that having alot of data would make the session the most viable solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several possible solutions, I suppose :

- Use cookies to store all data ; well, generally not quite a good idea :

  - Their size is limited
  - They go back and forth the network on each page load *(and also when requesting resources, such as CSS/JS/images)*
  - They are stored client-side
- Pass some identifier from one page to the next one *(using a parameter in the URL, or a hidden input in forms, typically)*, and use that identifier to fetch/store data somewhere

  - like in a database
  - or a memcached cluster
- or just use PHP sessions, which will do that for you, pretty much :

  - the identifier will generally be passed in a cookie,
  - the data will be stored in files, by default -- but you can have it stored in a database or memcached cluster quite easily.

Note though : sessions identifiers, in PHP, are generally passed using a cookie -- which is shared by all tabs in a browser.

Make sure your website will work with several tabs -- that the modifications in the session from one tab will not *break* the navigation in the other tabs !

Comment: How exactly do i take of the multitab situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass values between page in following ways:

- request params
- session
- cookies

Read [this](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=php_passing_variables.php) link for example.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "What's the best way of passing PHP variables between pages". In that case, the session is the correct answer. The session can handle any amount of data short of the memory limit in *php.ini*.

You have to run `session_start();` at the top of all your PHP pages in which you want to use the shared variables.

You can manage the session variables like an array:

```
<?php
    // Start/resume the session
    session_start();

    // Create a variable
    $myvariable = "Hello, world!";

    // Set the value of that variable to session
    $_SESSION["myvariable"] = $myvariable;

    // You can also set data directly to the session
    $_SESSION["anothervariable"] = "Bye, world!";
?>
```

Now you can access that data from any page like this:

```
<?php
    // Start/resume the session
    session_start();

    // Now you can fetch data from the same session variable
    echo $_SESSION["myvariable"]; // Hello, world!
    echo $_SESSION["anothervariable"]; // Bye, world!
?>
```

Tizag has a creat tutorial on working with the PHP session:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php, and passing data just from one page to another you can do it this way
page1.php

```
<a href="page2.php?somevalue=whatever&morevalue=somethingelse">Go to page 2</a>
```

page2.php

```
<?
   echo $_GET["somevalue"]; //it will print out whatever
   echo "<br />".$_GET["morevalue"]; // it will print out somethingelse
?>
```

But also read what others said :)

Answer (score 1):

In order of user accessibility (least to greatest):

- Session variables - `$_SESSION['var']`
- Cookies
- `$_POST['var']`
- `$_GET['var']`

Answer (score 1):

if you have a LARGE amount of data you need to move back and forth, saving that information to a database would probably be the most efficient.  It would save you the trouble of having to load all that info into a cookie/session/etc. and then having to de-multiplex on the other side when you want your information back.

By storing it in a database, you ensure that it will persist and you can come back and retrieve it at any time.