# Show image based on selection on other page

Tags: php, forms, post, radio-button, action

I have build a system to put together a shed, this is done with several pages with radio buttons and forms.

The problem is that with this form i use action and POST to send the result to the next page.
But i want the input for example on page 1 to be send to page 2 and 3, currently thats impossible because you can only have one action in your form.

```
<form action="lounge-kamer3.php" method="POST">
```

I need the input from page 1 for an if statement on page 2 and 3. how do i do that?
Couldnt find an easy way on the internet, and because i do not master english that well it sometimes is hard to understand.
Hope i am clear enough.

ps. sorry for my english, not my first language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try using a hidden field, a cookie, or session info to carry information across pages.

[How to pass information across web pages of a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765774/how-to-pass-information-across-web-pages-of-a-web-site)

You might want to write the requests asynchronously and then you can continually reuse info on the page with js and php.

Comment: Remember, though, there are security concerns when using hidden fields. ALWAYS sanitize to-be-executed inputs and be aware that hidden fields and dom storage methods (in general) are particularly vulnerable to simple tools like tamper-data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hidden fields.
In page 1, let's say 2 have 2 fields, in page 2, you have other 2 fields, but you actually have 4: 2 visible, and 2 hidden. These hidden fields must have the value: the `$_POST['field1']`

Example:
Page1.php:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="one">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php:

```
<form action="page3.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="one" value="<?php echo $_POST['one']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="two">
<input type="text" name="three">
<input type="submit">
```

page3.php:

```
<form action="end.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="one" value="<?php echo $_POST['one']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="two" value="<?php echo $_POST['two']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="three" value="<?php echo $_POST['three']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="four">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

end.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['one'];
echo $_POST['two'];
echo $_POST['three'];
echo $_POST['four'];
?>
```

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php

[hidden field in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949847/hidden-field-in-php)